# How can I make onClick apply to the label of a number form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, label

I have a page where with about 100 number forms. Each form has a different label, name, id, etc. This is to apply some other javascript later on.

Two questions: Is it possible to rig the javascript so the number form increases by one when clicking on the *label* (ie. click on "Apples") rather than the number box? And since every form has a different id, is it possible to grab each form by something other than its id (an alternate catch-all so it can easily be applied to around 100 different forms)?

Thank you in advance!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
    var i = 0;
    function onClick() {
        document.getElementById('applesQuantity').value = ++i;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<label>Apples </label><input type="number" name="apples-quantity" id="applesQuantity" onclick="onClick()">
<label>Oranges </label><input type="number" name="oranges" id="orangesQuantity" onclick="onClick()">

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use event delegation - watch for clicks on a `<label>`, and when seen, navigate to the element's `nextElementSibling` to get to the input, and increment it:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('label')) {
    const input = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    input.value = 1 + Number(input.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<label>Apples </label><input type="number" name="apples-quantity" id="applesQuantity": >
<label>Oranges </label><input type="number" name="oranges" id="orangesQuantity": >
```

Comment: Works like a charm :D

Comment: Awesome - thank you! That was a great fix :) Would it be possible to make the (e.target.matches('label')) only apply to number forms on the page? There are other forms on the page which are text forms and an accidental click on the label for those text forms changes the data inside it to 'NaN.'

Comment: @newbie101 You could give each label you care about a particular class or data attribute, then check against that selector instead. You could also check if the `input` is of type `number` before changing the value.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for that. Apologies, javascript isn't my forte. 
If attached to a class would it be something like: 
`(e.target.matches('label') && e.target.matches('.clickable'))`
or if attached to number type (which seems to be preferable) would it be something like:
`(e.target.matches('label') && e.target.matches('type=number'))` ?

Comment: @newbie101 `e.target.matches('label.clickable')` if you give it a class of `clickable`. Or, to check the input, `input?.matches('[type="number"]')`